# How can lite-server start on different machine?

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I created the Front-End side of my DApp, now to run it on the Ropsten Test Network I need to start lite-server (npm run dev) and it open up the browser with my index.html file.

If I open the file without lite-server the website doesn't work. It doesn't connect to the Network.

How can I put the website on-line without needing the visitors to use lite-server?

I hope that I explained it proprerly, sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are familiar with web-hosting, but you need to buy a domain name for your DApp and then host it somewhere. Decentralized options such as IPFS exist, or you could host it with regular centralized hosting options.